# Diferencia entre count(*) y count(nombre-de-columna)

Tags: mysql, sql

Al estar practicando consultas SQL me ha surgido una duda con la forma de realizar una. Quisiera saber qué diferencia hay entre:

> SELECT open_date, COUNT(*) FROM accounts

con esta otra

> SELECT COUNT(open_date) FROM accounts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La diferencia es que:

► **La primera consulta:  `SELECT open_date, COUNT(*) FROM accounts`**

Te va a devolver una sola fila con dos columnas, la primera columna tendrá el primer valor que encuentre del campo `open_date`, y la segunda columna te contará el total de registros en la tabla.

Como podrás comprender, pedir una columna adicional en el `SELECT` de esa manera no tendría mucho sentido.

Sin embargo, se puede usar `COUNT` con una columna adicional (o con varias), cuando quieres saber la cantidad de elementos que hay de esa(s) columna(s), combinándolo con `GROUP BY`.

Por ejemplo, si quieres saber cuántos animales hay de cada especie:

```
SELECT species, COUNT(*) FROM pet GROUP BY species;
+---------+----------+
| species | COUNT(*) |
+---------+----------+
| bird    |        2 |
| cat     |        2 |
| dog     |        3 |
| hamster |        1 |
| snake   |        1 |
```

Usando ese procedimiento, se pueden obtener conteos sobre varios tipos de columnas (para otros ejemplos ver los ejemplos de código en el enlace al final de esta respuesta).

---

► **La segunda consulta: `SELECT COUNT(open_date) FROM accounts`**

Te contará el total de registros de la tabla, **pero ignorando los valores `NULL` de la columna `open_date` si los hubiera**. Es decir que en ese caso podría no estar haciendo un conteo de todas la filas de la tabla.

---

► **En resumen:**

- **`COUNT(*)`**: contará todos los registros de la tabla. Se puede usar también `COUNT(1)`. No obstante, la forma que se suele usar es aquella con `*`.
- **`COUNT(columna)`**: contará todos los registros de la tabla en los que el valor de `columna` no sea `NULL`. Este uso no es seguro si se quiere saber cuántos registros hay en la tabla, independientemente de valores nulos.

Para más detalles y ejemplos puedes ver la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano por tu respuesta tan bien explicada y por el aporte de la documentación de MySQL. Le echare un vistazo.